# Django Token and Session auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-registration, django-rest-auth

I was creating a Login For Custom User model is work fine with django , now i try to convert into Rest .

It is creating the token but it doesnot return the token and Session is also blank

*(generation token but serializer.data is blank)*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ODG2.png)

*(Session db is empty)*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STWoI.png)

django **Serializer.py**

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
email = serializers.EmailField(
    required=False,
    allow_blank=True,
    write_only=True,
    label="Email "
)

password = serializers.CharField(
    required=True,
    write_only=True,
    style={'input_type': 'password'}
)

class Meta(object):
    model = User
    fields = ['email', 'password']

def validate(self, data):
    email = data.get('email', None)
    password = data.get('password', None)

    if not email:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Please enter email to login.")

    user = User.objects.filter(Q(email=email)).exclude(email__iexact="").exclude(email__isnull=True).distinct()
    if user.exists():
        user1 = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user1 is not None:
            if user1.is_active:
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user1)
                data['token'] = token
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Account not active.")
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid credentials.")
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("This email is not valid.")


    return data
```

Django **view.py**

```
class UserLogin(views.APIView):
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

def post(self, request):
    serializers = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    print(serializers)
    if serializers.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        print("data", serializers.data)
        return Response(serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializers.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add token field in the your serailizers.

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
email = serializers.EmailField(
    required=False,
    allow_blank=True,
    write_only=True,
    label="Email "
)

password = serializers.CharField(
    required=True,
    write_only=True,
    style={'input_type': 'password'}
)
token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta(object):
    model = User
    fields = ['email', 'password']

def validate(self, data):
    email = data.get('email', None)
    password = data.get('password', None)

    if not email:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Please enter email to login.")

    user = User.objects.filter(Q(email=email)).exclude(email__iexact="").exclude(email__isnull=True).distinct()
    if user.exists():
        user1 = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user1 is not None:
            if user1.is_active:
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user1)
                data['token'] = token
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Account not active.")
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid credentials.")
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("This email is not valid.")


    return data
    def get_token(self, obj):
        try:
            return Token.objects.get(user=obj).key
        except:
            return ''
```

Comment: It would be nice if you consider providing more information about what have you done to get this result.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield there is an explain in the this url

Comment: Bob I was creating a Music App which have User, Music, Playlis services. initially i create a simple Django model and its working fine now I'am changing that model to rest (I have 0 knowledge of rest i have learning while doing all this stuff). More info means you want me to share complete code.